# Does the dupe hammer apply to all tags?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer, tag-score

I appreciate the dupe hammer but does it apply to every tag? It's reasonable for specific tags like [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) but how does it apply for *generic* tags like [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image)?

Is someone with a gold badge on [image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image) an expert in any question, regardless of environment, about images? Is someone with a gold badge on [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) an expert on every shell?

With time (and older users still active) someone (if they haven't yet) will get a gold badge for generic tags, will the dupe hammer apply to them too?

I'm not suggesting it must be changed, I just want to know if the  same rule applies regardless of tag type.

Comment: That perhaps begs the question whether or not [image] and [shell] are actually good tags.

Comment: @bart I agree, I just picked two _random_ ones but there are tons of _generic_ tags to clarify context. For example [tag:C++] [tag:vector] (I just saw a high rep user with gold badge in [tag:vector]...) are reasonable tags to identify a C++ question about an issue with std::vector class...

Comment: I guess it really boils down to "is the dupe hammer abused?". If the answer is "no, not really", then I'm not sure these outliers (or whatever you want to call them) really matter.

Comment: If someone has a gold badge for a generic tag, the expectation is that they know where they're *not* an expert, and so won't use the dupe-hammer inappropriately.

Comment: @jon and bart I agree, someone with enough rep should also be _wise_ enough (BTW I forget I had to check Jon's tags...). Just for sake of discussion here I'm thinking about _mistakes_. I just have one poor gold badge and every time I have to think twice (or avoid to dupe-close). Someone like Jon with tons of that badges?

Comment: Some other gold badges are things like `list`, `string` and `arrays` etc...

Comment: @JonClements yes, I just searched some too. This post is more to ask how it will work in that cases than to suggest any change.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti as Jon says really... just be aware of what your dupe hammer will do and use it responsibly... if it's a C# question that's about `list`s (which you may well have a gold badge in from Python/other language), but you don't know anything about C#, then let others that have a gold in C# dupe it where needs be...

Comment: @JonClements I agree and you also implicitly answered my main question (dupe hammer applies regardless tag type). Do you mind to post it as answer?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You have an [awful lot of responsibility](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges&sort=class&page=1) on your shoulders then...

Comment: Related: [Let moderators disable the dupehammer for certain tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231509)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dupe hammer applies to *all* tags. There's no distinction between a tag that indicates a language, a framework, an algorithm etc...

**Rule of thumb**: If you're planning to close as a duplicate (dupe hammer available or not), then you should be *certain* it is indeed a duplicate.

**Example**
Let's say you have a gold badge in [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) (possibly earned from [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) or whatever) and you see a question tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) -- this means technically, you *could* dupe-close the question, but it doesn't mean you *should*.

You have one of two choices:

- If you're knowledgeable enough about [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) (even if you haven't got a gold badge yet) and the context and are *sure* you know a correct dupe, then yes, you *can* use your gold badge in [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) list to wield the hammer.
- Otherwise - leave it be and let the gold badge holders with the main domain expertise deal with it.

Comment: I wonder if a small checkbox "do not use dupe hammer in this case" may help. Maybe not and I'm just too _excited_ for my first gold badge on that...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Well... the user with the gold badge has spent enough time on the system to be given its trust they'll use it responsibly where necessary. It'd be a nightmare to categorise all the tags and not everyone will agree on what count as dupe-hammerable no doubt. Of course, if someone did mis-use it, I don't imagine it'd take very long for it to be brought to attention :)